# Why is it desirable to standardize the inputs of a Gaussian Process Regression?

Tags: gaussian-process, standardization, bayesian-optimization

I read this question ([Should we standardize the data while doing Gaussian process regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178245/should-we-standardize-the-data-while-doing-gaussian-process-regression)) and wondered, why do we need to normalize the inputs of a Gaussian Process?

In my case, I want to use Bayesian Optimization for maximizing several functions separately over, let's say, x_range. But due to prior knowledge of some functions, I can specify x_range to a smaller range. If I however normalize all ranges to [0,1], my lengthscale for instance would vary depending on the prior x_range. Thus, I do not see the benefit of the normalization.

Thank you for any input :)

Comment: I am not an expert, but I think that it would be hard to optimize the kernel parameters on different, but also big, input scales. Also, why don't you just change x_range and normalize afterwards?

Comment: What is x_range?